# How does the color of henna fade?

Tags: cell-biology, botany, human-physiology, pigmentation

[Henna](https://hennacolorlab.com/what-is-henna/) contain lawsone pigment that attaches to the proteins of the skin,hair,etc.But after a few weeks the color fades?

How does the color fade?

Is the pigment volatile or it is degraded by the body?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't become volatile nor is it degraded. Neither is really possible because the dye (lawsone) forms very strong bonds with protein molecules and also penetrates the skin quite well [source: [here](http://archive.boston.com/business/articles/2009/06/08/how_do_henna_tattoos_work/)].

Henna fades with time via [exfoliation](http://dh101.humanities.ucla.edu/DH101Fall12Lab5/exhibits/show/middle-east/methodology). In other words, it fades progressively as additional layers of skin die and [fall](http://leverett.harvard.edu/w/media/d/d0/Henna_Fact_Sheet.pdf) (*or* ["slough"](http://archive.boston.com/business/articles/2009/06/08/how_do_henna_tattoos_work/)) off.

Comment: Is the same for hair and nails

Comment: almost certainly....